# How to retrieve $_POST data from CURL

Tags: curl

I write a simple code to see how I can receive $_POST data using cURL:

**a.php**

```
$close = array('request'=>'1');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "b.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $close);
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

**b.php**

```
echo ($_POST);
```

I ran `a.php` but nothing happened. I also tried `$_POST["request"]` but nothing happened either.

**Update:**

I found the problem:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "b.php");
```

Changing to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/php/b.php");
```

It solves the problem. However, this is really inconvenient in the future when I use a different host. I will have to come back and change all the urls that use cURL. I hope there is a way to fix this.

**Update 2**
If cURL is an overkill, is there another way to send a POST or GET request from one php file to another php file?

Comment: It works for me. I assume that in your real code you set `CURLOPT_URL` to a real URL?

Comment: @Celada yeah I put b.php in the same folder as a.php

Comment: @Celada did you make any change to the code I posted? Or you just ran a.php and it prints out "1"?

Comment: I substituted an actual valid URL in the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL`... call where you have a placeholder string `"b.php"`, but other than that I ran it as is.

Comment: @Celada I think I know where the problem is. My url is not valid. I want to send POST request to the file b.php in the same folder (whose code I have posted above). How can I do that?

Comment: Yeah when I changed the url to `http://localhost/php/b.php`, it works. But this is really inconvenient when I upload the file to server, I have to come back and change it again. I hope there is another way around.

Comment: I don't really understand your concern. You are bothered by the fact that you actually have to give a valid URL to cURL? What did you expect?

Comment: @Celada Right now I am writing to code offline, so url works differently. For example, I want it to work like jQuery function `$.load('b.html')`. The load function use relative url; I don't have to write `http://localhost/b.html`. This is important because when I upload the code online, I won't have to go back and change every single url to match with new domain.